# Ubercart, replacing quantity input text with a dropdown box

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using the Ubercart car and I would like to replace the input field to specify the product quantities with a dropdown box.

In this way, customers don't have to type the number of items they want to buy but they can just select an item in the dropdown popup: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/dropdown.png

How can I replace it ?

Thanks

Comment: What if they want more than the quantity drop down allows?

Comment: they don't I've discussed it with my customer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in hook_form_alter().

```
if ($form_id == 'cart form') {
   $x = 0;
   $options = array();
   while ($x < 50) {
      $options[$x] = $x;
      $x++;
   }

   $form['qty']['#type'] = 'select';
   $form['qty']['#options'] = $options;
}
```

I did this off the top of my head, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to go into the code and change the form-array that is used for a product-ordering (set type to 'select' and set value to an array of values/labels). However if you don't want to touch the original code, you could:

1) Overwrite with a module using hook_form_alter()

2) Override with jQuery by creating a select-list and hiding the standard input then put the select list's value in the hidden input field on change. Example:

```
$('select#price').change(function() {
   var price = $('option:selected', this).value();
   $('input#price').val(price);
});
```

Comment: So, in both cases, I need to use hook_form_alter to replace with / add a select-list, right ?

Comment: in the first case yes, in the second case you have to use jQuery. Are you more experienced with jQuery or PHP?

Comment: I've changed the form with PHP. However this is not exactly what I want. See what I got now: (1) and what I would like have instead (2). [1] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/now.png [2] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/later.png

Comment: I dunno how to call it. It is not just a dropdown list. It is a drowdown button with a popup list.